# What would generate the message "Quote item is not found."

Tags: frontend

I have a module that emails me all frontend messages that are displayed to visitors.

Under what circumstance would the following message be displayed:

**Quote item is not found.**

I've tried to reproduce their steps but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Quote item is not found." error occurs when the given item that is currently in the customers shopping cart, has an item ID that does not match up with any value in the sales_flat_quote_item table.

This message can be displayed under the following circumstance:

```
Mage_Checkout_CartController::configureAction()
Mage_Checkout_CartController::updateItemOptionsAction()
Mage_Checkout_CartController::ajaxUpdateAction()
```

These three functions all appear to be responsible for modifications done to items already in the customers shopping cart.

```
Mage_XmlConnect_CartController::configureAction()
Mage_XmlConnect_CartController::updateItemOptionsAction()
```

Again, item modifications but through the XML Connect system.

This error is strange because by adding something to your cart, by its nature, it should exist in the sales_flat_quote_item table.

Either you are somehow changing the ID's stored on a quote level for the containing items and they no longer match up or the records are missing from the above table.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I just wanted to add that these messages are always generated from the same IP range leading me to believe it is malicious in some way.

Comment: Maybe not the case, its possible that the IP belongs to a customer with a corrupt cart stored in their session. Whenever they return to the site, they may be trying to modify their cart, and since it may be corrupted in some form, this error is occurring for them. Since you know the IP, look up their quotes in the sales_flat_quote table on the remote_ip column, then do a comparison with the quote items to see if you can spot something that is not consistent.